# why chrome asking to allow download multiple files

Tags: google-chrome

in my site chrome 50 asking to allow  download multiple files , please find the snapshot :

[image]

why this hapeend , and how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto the address `chrome://flags` and search for `parallel downloading`.
2. Change options for parallel downloading to `Enabled`

Not tested but flags change the behavior and this is most likely what you want